# The number '0' not working how I expect in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I had some strange behavior when synthesizing some code with the expression:

```
logic [7:0] x;
//...
if ((~x) == 0)
```

In a situation where `x` is `8'hff`), the above boolean evaluates to false. I saw this behavior in synthesized hardware and double-checked it in simulation.

Of course, changing the expression to

```
if ((~x) == '0)
```

Gives me the behavior I expect; It evaluates to true when `x` is `8'hff`.

**My question:**
Why does adding the tick mark fix this problem? `0` by itself should give me an unsigned integer with width 32, and `(~x)` should give me an 8-bit unsigned number. Whether or not I specify the width of my `0`, the result ought to be the same.

I assume that I'm missing something about signedness or type promotion in the Verilog spec.

**Example code:**
You can see this behavior across all Commercial simulators at [this EDA playground](https://edaplayground.com/x/N8YW) link.

In case you have trouble accessing it, the code at the link is

```
module tb;
  logic [7:0] x;
  logic [7:0] y;
  
  initial begin
    x <= 8'hff; 
    y <= 8'h00;
    
    #1;
    $display("((~x) == 0) evaluates to %b", (~x) == 0); #1;
    $display("((~x) == '0) evaluates to %b", (~x) == '0); #1;
    
    
    $display("((y) == 0) evaluates to %b", (y) == 0); #1;
    $display("((y) == 0) evaluates to %b", (y) == '0); #1;
    $display("((~y) == ~0) evaluates to %b", (~y) == ~0); #1;
    
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because operands get extended *before* apply any operations within the same context.

Since the width of the unsized decimal literal `0` is 32, the equality operator extends the width of the smaller operand to the width of the larger operand. So `8'hFF` becomes `32'h0000_00FF`. *Then* the bitwise-negation operator `~` gets applied.

The width of fill literal `'0` depends on its context. When self-determined, its width is 1 bit. However, when in the context of the equality operator, its width gets extended to the width of `x`, which is 8-bits.

You can get the behavior you want by using the fill literal, or making sure there is no operand extension either by:

```
if ((~x) == 8'b0) // No extension -- both sides are 8-bits
```

or use a concatenation:

```
if ({~x} == 8'b0)
```

The concatenation works because each operand of a concatenation is self-determined. Only the result of the concatenation is the context of the equality expression.

Comment: If the `(~x)` is in parenthesis, why would the extension happen before the negation? This seems like a violation of the order of operations that I asked for.

Comment: Table 11-21 of 1800-2012, (titled "Bit lengths resulting from self-determined expressions") says that the bit length of expression "op i where i is ~" is "L(i)". This implies to me that the length of `(~x)` should be 8.

Comment: Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify order of evaluation. But in any case, think of extension as an implicit operator that gets applied to the operand, not the expression the operand appears in. i.e. `(~(32'(x))) == 0`

Comment: @JohnM, except that `x` is not a self-determined expression--it is in the context of an equality. See sections _11.6.1 Rules for expression bit lengths_ and _11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression_